# How to increase session vue/cli 4.0.5 / vuex 3 / Laravel 6 Backend REST API app?

Tags: laravel, session-state

I make @vue/cli 4.0.5 / vuex 3 app with data reading from Laravel 6 Backend REST API app with passport
as auth and I want to set bigger time of logged session during development and for this in my 
app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php I changed time and session

```
protected function respondWithToken($token)
{
    $loggedUser = $this->guard()->user();

    $user_avatar_path = User::getUserAvatarPath($loggedUser->id, $loggedUser->avatar);
    $filenameData     = User::setUserAvatarProps($loggedUser->id, $loggedUser->avatar, true);

    return response()->json([
        'access_token'     => $token,
        'user'             => $loggedUser,
        'token_type'       => 'bearer',
        'user_avatar_path' => $user_avatar_path,
        'filenameData'     => $filenameData,
        'expires_in'       => $this->guard('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 660
    ]);
}
```

But seems this chages does not influence my app. Did I miss some options?
2) Also as I can see parameter expires_in starts its time from login time and that seems to me not what I want,
as I want this parameter works as time from last work in the app.
In other way any request to backend part I have to refresh this this parameter...

**MODIFIED :**
I read in “Passport Token Lifetimes” :

> By default, Passport issues long-lived access tokens that expire after
>   one year

Looks like that not the issue, as I have default options(one year).
Are the some options on vuejs side, when I use vue-resource

Here https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/api.md
 I see that vue-resource has timeout (number) option, but I am not sure how it is applicable?
 I login request :

```
 Vue.http.post(apiUrl + '/auth/login', userCredentials).then(response => {
    ...
```

?

**MODIFIED #2:**

I have in backend app:

```
"php": "^7.2",
"barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.4",
"laravel/framework": "^6.2",
"laravel/passport": "^8.1",
```

And on Vue/Cli part :

```
"store": "^2.0.12",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-js-modal": "^1.3.31",
"vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
"vue-router": "^3.1.3",
"vuex": "^3.1.2"
```

Actualy I want in backend app in config/app.php to set some parameter like

```
'personal_access_tokens_expire_in_hours' => 24, // Actually I think about value = 1
```

and to user it in 2 places :
in app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php :

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
    $personal_access_tokens_expire_in_hours   = config('app.personal_access_tokens_expire_in_hours',24);
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addHours($personal_access_tokens_expire_in_hours));
}
```

and in app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    $request->validate([
        'email'       => 'required|string|email',
        'password'    => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);

    if ( ! Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    $user = $request->user();
    $user->last_logged= Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));
    $user->save();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Access Token');
    $token       = $tokenResult->token;

    if ($request->remember_me) {
        $personal_access_tokens_expire_in_hours   = config('app.personal_access_tokens_expire_in_hours',24);
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addHours($personal_access_tokens_expire_in_hours);
    } // Though Ronak Dhoot wrote that $token->expires_at does not infleunce anything.
```

I added last_logged field to users and fill it on any login.

With default personalAccessTokensExpireIn value in 1 day I login in the system in the middle of my working day.
I turn off computer in the end of the day and opening it next morning I can enter my app with login I made 
yesterday(24 hours has not passed yet). That seems not safe for me.

I would prefer personalAccessTokensExpireIn = 1 hour and refresh it ANY authorized request from my vue/cli app.
In which way that could be done? Working on vue/cli apps with baxkend api which way do you use?

I have some prior work with auth/jwt and in app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php I found methods :

```
public function refresh() // THIS METHOD IS NOT CALLED ANYWHERE
{
    return $this->respondWithToken($this->guard()->refresh());
}

protected function respondWithToken($token)
{
    $loggedUser= $this->guard()->user();

    $user_avatar_path= User::getUserAvatarPath($loggedUser->id, $loggedUser->avatar);
    $filenameData                     = User::setUserAvatarProps($loggedUser->id, $loggedUser->avatar, true);

    $usersGroups=  User::getUsersGroupsByUserId($loggedUser->id, false);
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'user'         => $loggedUser,
        'token_type'   => 'bearer',
        'user_avatar_path'   => $user_avatar_path,
        'filenameData' => $filenameData,
        'usersGroups'  => $usersGroups,
        'expires_in'   => $this->guard('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 9360 // TOFIX
    ]);
}
```

Can refresh()  be used in my passport issue somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#token-lifetimes) to set expiry of token in laravel using passport

Answer (score 3):

The createToken() method creates a Personal Access Token. By default, these tokens expire after 1 year (or 100 years, if created by laravel/passport <= 1.0.11). The expiration time for this type of token is not modified by the Passport::tokensExpireIn() or Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn() methods.

**laravel/passport >= 7.0.4**

Passport version 7.0.4 added a new method Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn() that allows you to update the expiration time for personal access tokens. If you are on this version or later, you can add this method call to your AuthServiceProvider::boot() method.

```
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(1));
```

**laravel/passport < 7.0.4**

If you are not yet on passport version 7.0.4, you can still modify the personal access token expiration time, but it is more manual. You will need to enable a new instance of the personal access grant with your desired expiration time. This can also be done in your AuthServiceProvider::boot() method.

```
$server = $this->app->make(\League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer::class);
$server->enableGrantType(new \Laravel\Passport\Bridge\PersonalAccessGrant(), new \DateInterval('P100Y'));
```

**Note**:

Modifying the `expires_at` field in the database will not do anything. The real expiration date is stored inside the token itself. Also, attempting to modify the exp claim inside the JWT token will not work, since the token is signed and any modification to it will invalidate it. So, all your existing tokens will have their original expiration times, and there is no way to change that. If needed, you will need to regenerate new tokens.

**PS**:

These methods should be called from the `boot` method of your `AuthServiceProvider`.

Comment: I use some banks accounts with personal area. If I inactive with 15-20 minutes I lose my session and have to login again. That is what I want.